# Selector with context in jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

With jQuery, I do the following

```
MyCompaniesInfo = $('input[name^="Companies"]');
```

And the console gives me this (Firebug):

```
MyCompaniesInfo


Object[input b1280bf5...73a2a334, input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__IsExist False, input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__Type Company, 29 more...]

0 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__Name.text-box
1 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__phone.text-box
2 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__address.text-box
3 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__street.text-box
4 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__anotherthing.text-box
5 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__another.text-box
6 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__blabla.text-box
7 input#Companies_b1280bf5-102e-4592-a1b1-53e973a2a334__loremipsum.text-box

8 input#Companies_b1280bf52a1b1-53e973a2a334__Name.text-box
9 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__phone.text-box
10 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__address.text-box
11 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__street.text-box
12 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__anotherthing.text-box
13 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__another.text-box
14 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__blabla.text-box
15 input#Companies_b1280bf5a1b1-53e973a2a334__loremipsum.text-box
```

....

Now I want all fields that end in "Name", for example, so, I tried this:

```
$('input[name$="Name"]', MyCompaniesInfo).val('Name');
```

but that doesn't work.  How can I continue to select with jquery after `MyCompaniesInfo = $('input[name^="Companies"]');`?

Comment: If you post the link to the relevant image file one of us can, and probably will, include it in the question itself for you. Meanwhile, for formatting, have a read of the [editing-help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: That console ouput tells me nothing, but you can use multiple selector thingy's `$('input[name^="Companies"][name$="Name"]');`

Comment: Thank adeneo and David, that's working but i would to  use a context on this select `input[name^="Companies"]` because i make many manipulations

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use the first selector `MyCompaniesInfo = $('input[name^="Companies"]');` you'll store an array of elements in `MyCompaniesInfo`.

Then if you want to filter the elements you have to use `filter`, like the following.

```
$(MyCompaniesInfo).filter('input[name$="Name"]')
```

Why the following code won't work ?
`$('input[name$="Name"]', MyCompaniesInfo)`
Because it's the same of `$(MyCompaniesInfo).find('input[name$="Name"]')` and find only searches thrue the DOM tree, like it's being described on api.

`Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.`

Here you can see a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JppNb/).

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I tried : `$('input[name^="Companies"][name$="Number"]').val("test2");` that's working... but : `var MyCompaniesInfo = null; MyCompaniesInfo = $('input[name^="Companies"]'); $('input[id$="Name"]', MyCompaniesInfo);` or `$('input[name$="Name"]', MyCompaniesInfo);` that doesn't work... I don't know why... I must use `MyCompaniesInfo` because i'm doing many manipulation for this fields..

Comment: This is very inconsistent behavior, because the .filter method also says it works on a set of DOM elements.